# Help understanding possible world formalism

Tags: possible-worlds, formalisation

I am a total novice to philosophy trying to make sense of a computer science article which makes reference to possible world theory. I don't really understand the formalization in the last sentence below (see attached image for proper formatting). This is because I don't understand the word "arity" or the relation suggested by the superscript. It's be great if someone could lend some insight.

> Let S be an arbitrary system, D an arbitrary set of distinguished
>   elements of S, and W the set of world states for S (also called
>   worlds, or possible worlds). The tuple  is called a domain space
>   for S, as it intuitively ﬁxes the space of variability of the universe
>   of discourse D with respect to the possible states of S. An
>   intensional relation ρ^n of arity n on  n is a total function
>   ρ^n : W → 2^D^n from the set W into the set of all n-ary (extensional)
>   relations on D.

[image: excerpt from Handbook on Ontologies]

Answer (score 2):

The [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of a relation **R** is the number of its "argument places".

Thus, the relation "less than" is a *binary* relation: it has *arity* 2. We usually write: **x < y**, but we can write it "more formally" as: **<(x,y)**.

An *extensional* relation of arity **n** on **D** is a subset of **D^n** (i.e. **D x D x ... x D**: the set of all [n-uples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)).

The set of **all** *extensional* relations of arity **n** is **2^D^n** (i.e. the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of **D^n**).